Copy new files from one folder to another folder automatically
I have a problem and don't know how to solve it myself. I haven't found anything on google either.
I have a folder called Trace, in this folder several devices save their trace files. When the devices are in operation, new trace files are added. The trace files are all saved as "xxxxxx.trace". I have written a Powershell script that automatically turns all .trace files into txt files and then merges these txt files into one single txt file. The txt files are deleted after merging so that they are not copied several times into the merged txt file.
This is my Powershell script
while (1)
{
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Trace2"*.trace | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace '\.trace$','.txt' }
C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Powershell\Combine-Files.ps1 -output "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Test\test.txt" -source "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Trace2\" -filter "*.txt" -append 
Get-ChildItem C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Trace2\*.txt -File | Remove-Item -Force
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}

The script works, but the problem is that I am not allowed to delete the trace files from the original trace folder. For this reason I need a second folder. From now on I will call the original trace folder "folder1" and the second folder I will call "folder2".
These are the conditions that folder2 must fulfill:
-All files that are already on folder1, or will be added to it, must be copied to folder2.
-Each file is only allowed to be copied from folder1 to folder2 one time. So if a file is deleted in folder2, it cannot be copied from folder1 to folder2 again.
If this is not possible, a script or program that copies every newly added file in folder1 to folder2 would be another option. I would then manually copy the files that are already in folder1.
I have found this script and it almost does what i need, but because the files are deleted almost immediately from folder2, it is not possible to compare the files from folder1 and folder2 and see if the file has been copied before.
I have already tried robocopy /mir. However, robocopy /mir copies all files that were deleted from folder2 back into folder2, because robocopy /mir creates an exact image of folder1.
Edit 1:
This is the code from Sirtao's answer, where I have adjusted the paths.
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\dabetschart\Documents\Trace2"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.txt"
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
    $DestinationPath = "C:\Users\dabetschart\Documents\Test"

    $action = { 
                $FileCreated = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                Start-Sleep -Seconda 1
                Copy-Item -Path $FileCreated -Destination $DestinationPath
              }    
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}

The newly created files in Trace2 are not copied to Test. There are no error messages. I have the filter set to *.txt because I want to test the code with txt files first.
Edit 2:
I have found the problem. It worked with this code:
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\dabetschart\Documents\Trace2"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
    $DestinationPath = "C:\Users\dabetschart\Documents\Test"

    
### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 
                $Path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                Copy-Item -Path $Path -Destination $DestinationPath
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
### Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
### Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
### Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 1}

@sirtao Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot.

If the ultimate goal is to have a concatenated txt of all trace files the following could also work well enough:
while (1) {
    Get-ChildItem "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Trace2*.trace" |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | 
    Get-Content | 
    Set-Content "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Test\test.txt"
    
    Start-Sleep 10
}

It just creates the concatenated txt file every 10 seconds. Depending on the size of trace files and use of txt file it might be acceptable. The Sort-Object property can be adjusted as needed as well (sort by Name, CreationTime...)

Implementing this solution
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = '"C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Trace2'
$watcher.Filter = '*.trace'
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { 
    # get the full path of the file that has been created
    $FileCreated = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

    # wait one second after the creation of the file to make sure it's completely written. It shouldn't be an issue most of the time so test if you can remove it.
    Start-Sleep -Seconda 1

    # No need for other files you can get the content from the source
    Get-Content -Path $FileCreated | Add-Content 'C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Test\test.txt' 
}    

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -Action $action
# other events can have the same or different actions
# Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
# Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
# Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action


Thanks for the suggested solution. The code does not work for me. It could also be that I have done something wrong. I've only recently started working with powershell, so I'm not very familiar with it. As I understand the code, action is executed as soon as a file is created in the source folder and the path of the created file is stored in $FileCreated. Is there a way to copy not the content of the created file, but the whole file?

Sure: Copy-Item -Path $FileCreated -Destination $DestinationPath. If $DestinationPath is the name of a directory and not a file then the file original will be copied with the original name, otherwise it will get the new name. What is, exactly, that does not work?

I have tested the original code you linked. This code worked. When I run the code from your answer, nothing happens. But there is also no error message in Powershell.  I will edit the post and paste your code that I have customized.

What mechanism can be used to know that the file is fully written and closed? The device may write to the file for five (5) minutes. Hardcoding one (1) second wait time might not work.

@lit
This will not be a problem because the devices only upload the trace files when they have finished writing.

@Hagstuud, Is it possible that the upload could ever take more than one (1) second?

@lit, I don't think so, the file size of the trace files is only about 1-5 kilobytes.

@Hagstuud, the risk could be eliminated if the devices would upload files as a different name (.trc ?), then rename them to .trace.

@lit, I don't know if I can change the file type. This was programmed by the manufacturer of the devices. I have added a 5-second waiting time to my program. The upload should be completed within this time.
